# Passenger indicates no errors, but rails application does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

So, after troubleshooting for a couple days to get Passenger to load my rails application, I was previously getting some nice little Passenger errors when I navigated to my domain about gemset errors and database roles not being able to login. I believe I have fixed those setup errors, but now when I navigate to my domain, I get nothing. No error page, nothing. I can't find anything in the error log that indicates where my problem is. I suspect that the problem might be something to do with permissions, but I don't know how to diagnose whether this is correct or how to fix it. Here's what my error log looks like:

```
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:14 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:15 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:15 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.0461 3060/7f2d05770720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nobody', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/krstck/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/krstck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '3059', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '48', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '48' }
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.1385 3063/7f0d05adc720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3059/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.1523 3068/7f5fe481f7e0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3059/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.1528 3060/7f2d05770720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:15 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:15 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.3630 3082/7fad84082720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nobody', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/krstck/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/krstck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '3080', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '48', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '48' }
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.4069 3085/7fa13a7d6720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3080/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.4172 3090/7f6893bad7e0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3080/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-01 10:10:15.4177 3082/7fad84082720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Fri Nov 01 10:10:15 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Here's the output of passenger-memory-stats:

```
--------- Apache processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
3080  1     471.2 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3100  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3101  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3102  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3103  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3104  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3105  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3106  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
3107  3080  471.2 MB  0.1 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
### Processes: 9
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.36 MB


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


---- Passenger processes -----
PID   VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------
3082  209.8 MB  0.2 MB   PassengerWatchdog
3085  497.1 MB  0.3 MB   PassengerHelperAgent
3090  207.7 MB  0.5 MB   PassengerLoggingAgent
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.08 MB
```

Here's passenger-status:

```
Version : 4.0.21
Date    : 2013-11-01 10:35:58 -0500
Instance: 3080
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

Anything else I need to include? What could be getting in the way of loading my application?

Comment: may be <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661802/apache-server-keeps-crashing-caught-sigterm-shutting-down">this is the same thing</a> you are looking for...

Comment: I believe the SIGTERM was from when I had just restarted the server just then.

Comment: It starts fine on passenger standalone, in development mode, if that helps anyone diagnose.