# Apache2 won't start with phpMyadmin default module - OpenBSD 6.0

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, openbsd

I've installed phpMyadmin in OpenBSD 6.0 and when I do `cp  /var/www/conf/modules.sample/phpmyadmin.conf  /var/www/conf/modules/` and restart apache, it fails to work.

In error log it says:

`[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 35797] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

I have to remove /var/www/conf/modules/phpmyadmin.conf for apache to come back to life

phpmyadmin.conf content is:

```
# $OpenBSD: phpMyAdmin-httpd.conf,v 1.2 2013/01/18 15:17:43 giovanni Exp $

Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/www/phpMyAdmin

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache/modules/mod_rewrite.so

        RewriteEngine on

        # Allow only GET and POST verbs
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST)$ [NC,OR]



        # Ban Typical Vulnerability Scanners and others
        # Kick out Script Kiddies
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|wkito|pikto|scan|acunetix).* [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner).* [NC,OR]

        # Ban Search Engines, Crawlers to your administrative panel
        # No reasons to access from bots
        # Ultimately Better than the useless robots.txt
        # Did google respect robots.txt?
        # Try google: intitle:phpMyAdmin intext:"Welcome to phpMyAdmin *.*.*" intext:"Log in" -wiki -forum -forums -questions in
text:"Cookies must be enabled"
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(AdsBot-Google|ia_archiver|Scooter|Ask.Jeeves|Baiduspider|Exabot|FAST.Enterprise.Crawl
er|FAST-WebCrawler|www\.neomo\.de|Gigabot|Mediapartners-Google|Google.Desktop|Feedfetcher-Google|Googlebot|heise-IT-Markt-Crawle
r|heritrix|ibm.com\cs/crawler|ICCrawler|ichiro|MJ12bot|MetagerBot|msnbot-NewsBlogs|msnbot|msnbot-media|NG-Search|lucene.apache.o
rg|NutchCVS|OmniExplorer_Bot|online.link.validator|psbot0|Seekbot|Sensis.Web.Crawler|SEO.search.Crawler|Seoma.\[SEO.Crawler\]|SE
Osearch|Snappy|www.urltrends.com|www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~crawler|SynooBot|crawleradmin.t-info@telekom.de|TurnitinBot|voyager|
W3.SiteSearch.Crawler|W3C-checklink|W3C_Validator|www.WISEnutbot.com|yacybot|Yahoo-MMCrawler|Yahoo\!.DE.Slurp|Yahoo\!.Slurp|Yaho
oSeeker).* [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/phpMyAdmin>
        AllowOverride All

        # Default to only permitting access from localhost.
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Comment: That error doesn't make a whole lot of sense; does it really appear at the same time you are trying to access phpMyAdmin? Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661802/apache-server-keeps-crashing-caught-sigterm-shutting-down#1661888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change this directory permision from:

```
<Directory /var/www/phpMyAdmin>
 AllowOverride All
 Order deny,allow 
Deny from all 
Allow from 127.0.0.1 
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/phpMyAdmin>

Require all granted 
 </Directory>
```